# How to generate all combinations from key of JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to generate object B which contains all combination of other object A using  key and value:

```
{
  "x": "data-x",
  "y": "data-y",
  "z": "data-z"
}
```

I need the result like this:

```
{
  "x": "data-x",
  "y": "data-y",
  "z": "data-z",
  "x+y": "data-xy",
  "x+z": "data-xz",
  "y+z": "data-yz",
  "x+y+z": "data-xyz",
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an recursive approach by handing over the array of keys and call the function again wih the rest of the keys and an array of the collected keys.

For each round store the combined key in the object and check the length of the array and exit if no more items are available.

Otherwise call the function again with an array without the actual key and with it.

```js
function getAll(object) {
    function iter([value, ...array], left) {
        var right = left.concat(value);
        result[right.join('+')] = 'data-' + right.map(key => object[key]).join('+');
        if (!array.length) return;
        iter(array, left);
        iter(array, right);
    }
    var result = {};
    iter(Object.keys(object), []);
    return result;
}

var data = { x: "X", y: "Y", z: "Z" };

console.log(getAll(data));
```